# Does it follow that two finite positive measures are the same?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $\mu$ and $\nu$ are finite positive measures on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[0, 1]$ such that $\int f\,d\mu = \int f\,d\nu$ whenever $f$ is real-valued and continuous on $[0, 1]$. Does it follow that $\mu = \nu$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's true that $\mu=\nu$. First, recall that if two finite Borel measures satisfy $\mu([a,b])=\nu([a,b])$ for all closed intervals $[a,b]\subset [0,1]$, then $\mu=\nu$. This is because the set of closed intervals $[a,b]\subset [0,1]$ is a $\pi$-system which generates the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,1]$.

So fix an interval $[a,b]\subset [0,1]$, and choose a sequence of continuous functions $f_n(x)$ which decrease to $1_{[a,b]}$. Then by the monotone convergence theorem,
$$ \mu([a,b])=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n\;d\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n\;d\nu=\nu([a,b]) $$
as desired.

Comment: The indicator of $[a,b]$ is *upper* semi-continuous, so it's possible to find a *decreasing* sequence of continuous functions converging pointwise to $1_{[a,b]}$. Monotone convergence still applies.

Comment: @JohnDawkins: good point. I suppose I could also have picked open intervals.

Comment: You could take $f_n(x) = 1 - d(x,[a,b])^n$ for example.